# Configuration Setup for Asp.net mvc 3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, configuration, web-config, configuration-management

i have an asp.net mvc 3 application that i want to deploy but i want to somehow automate the deployment process of the application. For example if i upload code to http://www.domain.com. when site is run for the first time it should check if database is setup if not it should run the sql server scripts from the scripts folder to user's specified server for his specified database. Then there are some settings that it should accept from the user and store in web.config like smtp, Official Email, phone etc. These are settings that are required only once in the lifetime of the application. Then there are settings that application should prompt at the end of the financial year.
what is best way (even a way would be highly appreciable) of doing this kind of stuff in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than outlining the whole process here, I will instruct you to check the Orchard setup, it does something similar, you might want to check out how they do it:
http://orchardproject.net/

Comment: is there a specific article on orhard site or i have to download and install to check out their procedure

Comment: You will have to dive into the source I guess..you might also want to check out how they handle settings storage and updating too.